# Is it possible to resolve filter rounding errors between MATLAB and Python?

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to replicate some Matlab code into Python and at the moment im developing a unit test to check for equivalence. In the code below I get errors in the order of E-11 which indicates to me that it could possibly be a rounding error.

Matlab Code:

```
width = 200;
x = 1:100000;
b = ones(width,1)/width;
y = filter(b, 1, x);
save('mat_data')
```

Python Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import loadmat
from scipy import signal

def plot_fig(x, y=None):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    if y is None:
        y = x
        x = np.arange(0, len(y))
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()

def mat_data(param):
    data = loadmat('mat_data.mat')
    return np.squeeze(data[param])

y = signal.lfilter(mat_data('b'), 1, mat_data('x'), axis=0)
plot_fig(mat_data('y') - y)
```

I have used the `loadmat` function to ensure equivalence between the numerical arrays I use as function inputs. The resulting plot is:

[difference plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQK52.png)

I see that the error is small, so could be rounding errors, but it does also seem to accumulate which worries me.

At the moment the application I'm working on is critical to ensure the binary equivalence between the two codes (matlab and python) so I would greatly appreciate any help in resolving this disparity.

Thanks in advance,

A.

Answer (score 0):

You could try double precision floats rather than single precision in python.
I think that would reduce accumulating rounding error significantly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The default numpy float is already double precision as far as I know. In any case I modified a line in my code to `return np.squeeze(data[param]).astype(np.float64)`

and I saw no change in the output